# resharper extract interface grayed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

how to create an interface off of a class using resharper?
the option is grayed out.

VS does have an option for refactoring the interface out of the class but resharper takes it out by default.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The menu is **context-sensitive**, you have to right-click precisely the **class name**. From your example, I can see that "Go to Implementation" is greyed out so you clearly clicked the background.

Once you right-click the class name, the correct menu options will be enabled.

[image]

Comment: In my case, even when right-clicking on classname, the extract interface is grayed out. This was working before....:(

Comment: but... restart VS helped :)

Answer (score 7):

Don't mark the classname by double clicking it, but just place the cursor inside it and press the right mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the class name (Note that it's NOT double-click to select the whole name), then either right click or Ctrl+Shift+R to bring up the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by opening the solution from source control explorer rather than from a local sln file.